# Google Chrome does not support function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an issue with a function that doesn't run on Google chrome but runs successfully on IE. I really need it to run on Chrome.

```
function SubmitForm(){

 if(textbox2.value=="OFFERED RATE"){
    alert(" C o n g r a t u l a t i o n s ! \n You are absolutely CORRECT");
    location.href='list_quiz.html';
}else
alert("Sorry, You are WRONG.\n The correct answer is OFFERED RATE");
    location.href='list_quiz.html';
}
<button onclick="SubmitForm()">Submit New</button>
```

kindly assist with what is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Post a demo here http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Chrome allows for inline scripts as long as it's not a chrome extension. This isn't a chrome extension since tested in IE, but could still be an extension that was ported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

HTML FILE

```
<button id="submit_form">Submit New</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
button = document.getElementById('submit_form')
button.addEventListener("click", SubmitForm, false);
```

Then you will also have to change your `SubmitForm()` function to get the `textbox2` value as follows:

```
answer = document.getElementById('textbox2').value
if (answer=="OFFERED RATE"){
...
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add the third parameter to addEventListener of "false". In most browsers it's optional, but some still require it.

Comment: I used the above and it still didn't work, both for chrome and IE

Comment: @user3449483, What error did you get? Also, can you please post a jsfiddle.net

Comment: There was no error. It just doesn't respond. How do i post on jsfiddle.net? I'm new here.

Comment: @user3449483, Sorry, forgot the `.value` part. Should work now. Also, if you are posting your `form` somewhere, remove the post part.

Comment: can't load my full script here

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/yPaXa/2/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: @user3449483, Got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/yPaXa/3/

You should add the two lines of code that I showed in my answer, outside the function as I have updated on this jsfiddle